If $u(t,x) = \int_0^t \theta(s,x)\;\mathrm{d}s$ and $\theta \geq 0$ is it true that $\chi_{\{\theta > 0\}} = \chi_{\{u > 0\}}$ for $t>0$?
Let $\theta(t,x) \geq 0$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ and $x \in \bar\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is some bounded domain. Define the integral
$$u(t,x) = \int_0^t \theta(s,x)\;\mathrm{d}s$$
Assume that $\theta$ is as regular as is needed. Is it true that
$$\chi_{\{\theta > 0\}} = \chi_{\{u > 0\}}$$ for $t>0$?
I saw this claim on page 4 of this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00046685
But I couldn't show it. Because it's possible for $u(t,x)>0$ but $\theta(t,x)=0$... am I missing some assumptions?

I'd guess equalities between functions are really meant almost everywhere or in the sense of distributions.

You're certainly missing some assumptions for the reasons you already mentioned. Some more context from the paper would be helpful.
